# Get data from callback before finishing function AWS Nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a lambda function to [create new IAM user in AWS using Nodejs SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#createUser-property), the function `iam.createUser()` works great but I couldn't retrieve the callback data before my function finishes. I'm not familiar with Nodejs so here I am asking for experts' help.

Here's the piece of code where I call `createUser()`:

```
var retMessage = '';
var params = {
  UserName: "foo.bar";
};
iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    retMessage = err;
  } else {
    retMessage = data;
  }
}); 
console.log(retMessage);
```

When my function finishes, all i got from `retMessage` is null.

So how do I get those callback values?

Comment: Your console.log is happening before the function finishes. Keep in mind that javascript is asynchronous, meaning it fires off createUser, then calls console.log, **it will not wait for createUser** before moving on

Comment: @Derek well that's why I asked the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just move the `console.log` (or data handling) call *inside* the callback? Like

```
var params = {
  UserName: "foo.bar";
};
iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    retMessage = err;
  } else {
    retMessage = data;
  }
  console.log(retMessage);
  // ...do your data handling...
});
```

Comment: My point is I need the value of `retMessage` outside of this function

Comment: I think there's now way to do that with a callback. If you need a more "synchronous" style you should try something else, promises for instance.